# How to create listview to download pdf files?

Tags: android, listview

I would like to make simple listview, when click on it download pdf file.
I tried for a long time to do that but failed .

this is xml layout for my app, so if there is wrong please help me. i am new in android studio

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.asus.myapplication.develop1_list_progrme">
    <include layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"></include>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="260sp"
        android:background="#C3E2DC"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/progra_2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:ignore="ScrollViewSize">



    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_pro"
        android:layout_width="300sp"
        android:layout_height="380sp"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40sp"
        android:scrollbarSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        tools:ignore="NestedScrolling,RtlHardcoded" />


</RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

```html
package com.example.asus.myapplication;

import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class develop1_list_progrme extends AppCompatActivity {
    DownloadManager downloadManager;
    ListView mListView_pro;
    private String [] pro ={"Chapter 1: Introduction ", "Chapter 2: Basic definitions",  "Chapter 3: Numerical conversions","Chapter 4: Logical gates"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_develop1_list_progrme);
        ListView mListView_pro = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_pro);
        Toolbar my_toolbar= (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(my_toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Semester(2)");
        getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle("أساسيات برمجة");

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, pro){
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
                /// Get the Item from ListView
                View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

                TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                tv.setHeight(200);
                tv.setMinimumHeight(200);
                // Set the text size 25 dip for ListView each item
                tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,25);

                // Return the view
                return view;
            }
        };

        mListView_pro.setAdapter(adapter);
        mListView_pro
                .setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {


                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        if(position == 0) {


                                downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                                Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://letterless-pulls.000webhostapp.com/itro_pro.pdf");
                                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
                                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                                Long reference = downloadManager.enqueue(request);

                        }
```

please help me

Comment: YOu create a listview. You add the touch listener. You download when it is clicked. Is that so complicated? Further, what failed? Any errors? Did you check to make sure oyu have the appropriate permissions?(INTERNET, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, because of lacking code, some parts of this answer is basically a guess.

---

IN your manifest, add the following lines:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

If this doesn't help, please add your Manifest and the stacktrace(if present/if there is a crash) to the question

---

See [this github repo](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/blob/master/Internet/Download/src/com/commonsware/android/download/DownloadDemo.java) by CommonsWare for a more detailed explanation on downloading files.